# Como checar se um arquivo existe usando Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Como checar se um arquivo existe, em Python, sem usar um bloco `try:`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Você pode fazer:

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile('nome do arquivo')
```

Mas essa abordagem não é considerada a mais pythônica. Seguindo o princípio que é melhor pedir perdão que permissão, é melhor fazer:

```
try:
   with open('nome_do_arquivo', 'r') as f:
       processar_arquivo(f)
except IOError:
    print u'Arquivo não encontrado!'
```

`os.path.isfile()` e `os.path.exists()` só informam que o arquivo ou diretório existiam no momento em que aquela linha de código estava sendo executada. No (minúsculo) espaço de tempo entre a execução dessa linha e a execução do código que depende dessa verificação, é possível que o arquivo possa ter sido criado ou deletado.

Esse tipo de situação é uma *race condition*, que pode causar vulnerabilidades de segurança. Um ataque possível seria criar um symlink para um arquivo qualquer imediatamente após o programa checar se o arquivo existe ou não. Dessa forma, um arquivo poderia ser lido ou sobrescrito utilizando o mesmo nível de acesso e privilégios que o seu programa possui.

Comment: usando try, except é a melhor maneira mesmo :)

Comment: Não é questão de ser pythonica ou não, é de ser certo ou não. Se quer saber se o arquivo existe é a primeira, e ela é pythonica se o tal jeito pythonico for fazer o certo. Se ele incentivar as pessoas fazerem errado não quero seguí-lo. Se o que deseja não é saber se o arquivo existe, mas sim usar o arquivo e se o arquivo não existir, o que impede de fazer o que deseja, aí deve tratar o erro, e a segunda forma é a correta. Seria um absurdo tentar fazer lago com um arquivo só para saber se ele existe, só porque alguém disse que assim é o certo em alguma doc da linguagem, se é que isso existe.

Answer (score 7):

Tente assim:

```python
import os.path
print os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Há o método [`os.path.exists()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.exists) também, mas note que ele retorna verdadeiro para diretórios.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar [exists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.exists):

```
import os.path
os.path.exists('nome.ext')
```

Mas que também vai retornar `True` para diretórios, se você quer ter certeza de que é um arquivo realmente use [isfile](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.isfile):

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile('nome.ext')
```