# Como implementar journaling em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso fazer uma série de operações envolvendo arquivos binários (não dá pra usar BD), e preciso garantir que elas terminem com sucesso mesmo em caso de falha no meio da operação. Para isso, não vejo saída a não ser implementar um sistema de [*journaling*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling) manualmente. Comecei a escrever um código, mas não estou seguro se está correto (i.e. se não existem casos em que uma falha no meio da tarefa pode colocá-lo em um estado inconsistente - inclusive falha na própria escrita do *journal*).

Existe algo pronto nesse sentido? E se não existe, há algum problema na minha tentativa de solução abaixo?

```python
def nova_tarefa(args):
    refazer_journal() # Refaz o que ficou inacabado da última vez (se houver)
    with open('args.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(args, f) # Prepara as novas tarefas
    with open('journal.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('comecar\n') # Coloca as novas tarefas no journal
    refazer_journal() # Faz as novas tarefas

def refazer_journal():
    try:
        with open('journal.txt', 'r') as f:
            passos = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if x.strip()]
    except:
        if not os.path.exists('journal.txt'):
            passos = []
        else:
            raise
    if not passos: # Se não há nada inacabado, termina
        return
    with open('args.json', 'r') as f:
        args = json.load(f)

    # Realiza as tarefas que ainda não foram marcadas como concluídas
    for indice,tarefa in enumerate(args['tarefas']):
        if len(passos) <= indice+1:
            realizar_tarefa_indepotente(tarefa)
            with open('journal.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('\ntarefa concluida\n')

    with open('journal.txt', 'w') as f:
        pass # Tudo foi feito com sucesso: esvazia o journal
```

(Nota: o que está escrito no *journal* - `comecar`, `tarefa concluida` - não é importante, se apenas uma letra que seja for escrita na linha já se considera que o passo foi bem-sucedido)

Código para teste (comigo funcionou sempre - inclusive editando o `journal.txt` para introduzir uma série de erros):

```python
def realizar_tarefa_indepotente(tarefa):
    if 'falhar' in tarefa:
        raise Exception('Tarefa falhou!')
    print 'Realizando tarefa: ' + tarefa['nome']

tarefa_ok = {'tarefas':[{'nome':'foo'}, {'nome':'bar'}, {'nome':'baz'}]}
falha_3 = {'tarefas':[{'nome':'foo'}, {'nome':'bar'}, {'nome':'baz','falhar':True}]}
falha_2 = {'tarefas':[{'nome':'foo'}, {'nome':'bar','falhar':True}, {'nome':'baz'}]}
falha_1 = {'tarefas':[{'nome':'foo','falhar':True}, {'nome':'bar'}, {'nome':'baz'}]}
falha_1_3 = {'tarefas':[{'nome':'foo','falhar':True}, {'nome':'bar'}, {'nome':'baz','falhar':True}]}
```

Comment: Nota: é do meu entendimento que revisão de código (*code review*) [faz parte do nosso foco (é *on topic*)](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/215) atualmente. Se alguém não concorda, favor se manifestar no meta.

Comment: Não quis colocar isso como resposta, já que é só um link, mas acho interessante documentar. [Essa solução](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.journal) te satisfaz?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar A maioria dos recursos que achei ao buscar por "python journal" se referia não a [*journaling*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling) [no contexto de sistema de arquivos] mas à implementação de alguma espécie de "diário"... Creio que esse link também se trata disso - já que é um plugin para o plone (sistema de CMS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escrevi um artigo que descreve como fazer isto: http://epx.com.br/artigos/arqtrans.php e inclusive um cidadão fez uma implementação em Python baseado no artigo: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/acidfile/1.2.0

A técnica básica é escrever dois arquivos no mínimo. Primeiro um, depois o outro em modo síncrono - conforme foi descrito em outras respostas.

O "tempero" do esquema é adicionar timestamp e um somatório (hash) nos dois arquivos. Dessa forma podemos saber qual é o arquivo mais recente - pelo timestamp - podendo verificar se o arquivo está íntegro (pelo hash).

O sistema de arquivos deve implementar journaling pelo menos dos meta-dados  (geralmente é o caso, journaling dos dados custa performance). Isto garante que pelo menos a pasta e o arquivo sejam legíveis. Se os dados estiverem corrompidos você detecta pelo hash.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava procurando! Melhor do que reinventar a roda... Vou testar essa implementação que você citou, mas já dei uma olhada nos fontes e me parece que está tudo ok.

Comment: Acabei por utilizar sua solução: agora eu salvo o próprio `args.json` como um `ACIDFile` - assegurando de só atualizá-lo após me certificar que a tarefa anterior completou com sucesso (ver [resposta do @utluiz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5825/215)). Simplificou bastante o código.

Answer (score 4):

- Um problema facilmente visível na sua implementação é que a forma que você checa pra ver se o arquivo `journal.txt` existe após a leitura está sujeita a race conditions, vide [Como checar se um arquivo existe usando Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2823/como-checar-se-um-arquivo-existe-usando-python?rq=1).
- Além disso, o ideal é, não capturar exceções "naked", e sim definindo o tipo específico de exceção que você espera, p.ex. `IOError`, `OSError`, etc. Da mesma forma, quando for `raise` uma exceção, é bom utilizar [uma com um nome específico relacionado ao tipo de erro](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).
- Para iterar sobre o dicionário, como uma alternativa, ao invés de iterar sobre o resultado do `enumerate()`, você pode simplesmente iterar sobre a lista:

  ```
  passos = [{'nome':'foo','falhar':True}, {'nome':'bar'}, {'nome':'baz'}]
  for tarefa in passos:
      realizar_tarefa_indepotente(tarefa)
  ```
- A forma que você checa se o valor 'falhar' funciona, mas não é muito explícita. Recomendaria trocar por `if 'falhar' in tarefa.items()`, se você estiver simplesmente checando se ela existe, ou `if tarefa.get('falhar')` se você quiser certificar-se que o valor de `tarefa['falhar']` é `True`.

Comment: Uma dúvida sobre o item #1: o `try` já não faz exatamente isso, solicitando a leitura do arquivo? Deveria então haver um outro bloco try aninhado?

Comment: Não precisa, você pode simplesmente retirar o bloco `if` já que se ocorrer exceção dentro do `try` o arquivo provavelmente não existe. Seguindo o bullet seguinte, você poderia checar por exceções diferentes e tratar casos diferentes (p.ex. arquivo não existe, acesso negado, etc).

Comment: Certo, entendi. Obrigado!

Comment: Sobre o item #3, **acho** que a ideia é não executar os passos que já foram executados. Por exemplo, se há 3 passos gravados no `journal.txt`, as tarefas serão executadas da 4ª em diante. Nesse caso, a não ser que o índice seja usado para alguma outra coisa no código real, talvez pudesse ser feito algo como `for tarefa in args['tarefas'][len(passos):]:`.

Comment: Entendi. Minha preferência pessoal seria por iterar sobre esses itens de qualquer forma e ignorá-los em seguida. Outra alternativa é filtrar a lista (p.ex.: `args['tarefas'] = [x for x in args['tarefas'] if x.get('falhar') is False]`), mas com isso você perde a informação sobre índices e a quantidade de itens que já foram feitos e pode demorar um pouco caso o número de itens seja grande.

Comment: Ou ainda: já que o seu arquivo `journal.txt` só guarda o número de tarefas que foram executadas com sucesso, você poderia gravar simplesmente o número, incrementando-o a cada sucesso e utilizando-o ao invés de `len(passos)` para pular as tarefas que foram executadas com sucesso.

Comment: [sobre o último comentário] isso não é possível, pois há o risco de eu corromper o `journal.txt` se houver falha durante a manipulação do mesmo. No modo que eu fiz, **ou** uma linha nova será adicionada ao arquivo (confirmando a tarefa) **ou** não (exigindo que ela seja refeita depois). [sobre #1 e #2] Boa sugestão, vou fazer! [sobre #3] A sugestão do @utluiz é boa. Eu preciso ignorar tarefas já feitas pois, embora cada tarefa individual seja indepotente **no estado correto do sistema**, ela não o é se o sistema já mudou de estado (i.e. se a tarefa seguinte já começou).

Answer (score 3):

## Garantia da gravação dos arquivos

Meu primeiro pensamento quando se trata de garantir o processamento de arquivos foi o ***buffer*** de dados.

Veja o que diz a documentação do [`file.flush()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush):

> Nota: o flush() não necessariamente escreve os dados do arquivo para o disco. Use `flush()` seguido por `os.fsync()` para garantir o comportamento. (tradução livre)

Suponho que as tarefas podem ter um volume bem maior de dados do que o `journal.txt`. Se ocorrer uma queda de energia no final do método `refazer_journal()`, o *journal* pode ter sido gravado no disco enquanto os dados das tarefas ainda estão em buffer.

Eu entendo que os dados do *journal* são enviados **depois**, mas não creio existir uma garantia de que o *buffer* será enfileirado sequencialmente pelo sistema operacional e pelo hardware.

Comment: Boa observação! Vou fazer isso e, pra garantir, também uma verificação dos arquivos recém-escritos para confirmar que está tudo ok **antes** de confirmar a tarefa. (e se entendi bem, é importante que o `os.fsync` seja usado também depois de se escrever o journal - para evitar que a tarefa seguinte comece sem que a registro de conclusão da tarefa anterior esteja pronto, certo?)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim, acredito que a sincronização deva ser feita após todas as gravações.

Comment: Li ainda algum lugar (acho que foi no Linux System Programming) que o sync deveria ser feito 2 ou 3 vezes, como é o costume dos admins UNIX na linha de comando. Não lembro a razão exata, é algo como: o primeiro sync só inicia a gravação física, mas o segundo sync efetivamente bloqueia antes do primeiro terminar (se ainda não terminou).

Comment: @epx Wow! Aí o nível baixou muito pra mim... rsrs

Answer (score 2):

Crie um journaling baseado em arquivos no filesystem. Sugiro usar uma nomenclatura baseada em epoch... Escrever e apagar itens de uma única vez é sempre mais seguro que manipula-lo milhares de vezes. O próprio journaling pode ser corrompido, já que atomicidade em python é dificil de garantir pra processos longos.