# Para que serve o arquivo Journal no Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Quando criei um banco em SQLite no Android, notei um arquivo com o nome da tabela, seguido de -journal.
O que é isso e para que serve?

Estranhei este arquivo ter permissões diferentes e usar um icone de tabela em um aplicativo de explorer...

[image: journal]

Comment: Possível explicação [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10046596)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O propósito de um [***journal***](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling) ("diário") é garantir a **atomicidade** das alterações feitas nos dados do banco: digamos que você tenha uma transação com 3 inserts/updates/deletes; como garantir que **ou** os três tenham sucesso **ou** os três falhem? Como garantir que, por exemplo, você não subtraia fundos de uma conta bancária e, antes de acrescentar esses fundos na outra, o computador trave e esses fundos desapareçam?

Isso é feito através de um arquivo especial, que registra todas as transações que vão sendo realizadas até o momento de sua conclusão. Um exemplo (fictício) seria:

```
iniciou transação
fez insert na tabela X com os valores A
fez insert na tabela Y com os valores B
fez update na tabela Z com os valores C; os valores antigos eram D
commit
```

Quando você inicia a transação, o banco está no seu estado original; quando você faz o primeiro `insert`, ele guarda os novos dados numa região temporária (exemplo; cada banco pode fazer isso de uma forma diferente); idem pro segundo; idem pro `update`; quando você faz commit, ele pega os dados do primeiro `insert` e colocam na tabela definitiva; idem pro segundo e pro `update`; uma vez pronto, ele apaga o *journal*.

Pra que isso tudo? Simples:

- Se o computador travar antes do commit, ao reiniciar o banco lê o journal, vê que não houve commit, e joga fora a transação inteira;
- Se o computador travar depois do commit, ao reiniciar o banco lê o journal, vê se cada transação individual já teve seus dados movidos pra tabela definitiva, e se não tiver ele completa a operação;

  - Se o computador travar *de novo* enquanto ele está fazendo isso, na próxima vez que ligar começa tudo de novo...
  - Quando ele finalmente conseguir terminar a transação, só aí ele apaga o *journal*.
- Se o computador travar depois de um rollback, ao reiniciar o banco lê o journal, vê se cada transação individual já foi **desfeita** (não se aplica a nosso exemplo, onde as alterações só são confirmadas no final, mas outras estratégias podem exigir isso), e se não foi ele completa a operação;

  - Se o computador travar *de novo* enquanto ele está fazendo isso...
  - Ao terminar, apaga o *journal*.
- Se o computador travar quando o *journal* estiver vazio/ausente, ao religar ele sabe que não há nenhuma transação "no meio do caminho", então ele pode continuar numa boa.

Note que, se não houver *journal* em arquivo, **não se pode garantir a atomicidade de nenhuma transação!** [Na pergunta indicada por Papa Charlie nos comentários](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10046596/520779) o AP pede por uma maneira de desabilitá-lo (i.e. fazer com que o *journal* só exista em memória / não exista em absoluto). Se não tiver uma boa razão pra fazer isso, não faça: caso contrário, suas transações podem ficar incompletas (a menos é claro que você não possua nenhuma transação complexa que demande atomicidade).

E caso eu não tenha sido claro, isso vale inclusive pra "transações" com uma única operação (estou incerto quanto a operações *fora* de uma transação, mas por segurança eu assumiria que também é o caso). Citando [a documentação do SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode):

> O modo de journaling `MEMORY` guarda o diário de *rollbacks* em RAM volátil. Isso economiza E/S de disco mas às custas de segurança e integridade do banco de dados. Se uma aplicação usando SQLite trava no meio de uma transação quando o modo `MEMORY` estiver ativo, então provavelmente o arquivo do banco de dados ficará corrompido.
>
> O modo de journaling `OFF` desabilita o diário de *rollbacks* completamente. Nenhum diário é criado e portando nunca há um arquivo a se remover. (...) Se uma aplicação usando SQLite trava no meio de uma transação quando o modo `OFF` estiver ativo, então provavelmente o arquivo do banco de dados ficará corrompido.

**Referências adicionais:**

- [Essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1932/215) à pergunta "Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?"
- [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5940/215) à minha pergunta "Como implementar journaling em Python?"